# Is it possible to inherit the implementation of an interface

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface

is it possible to inherit the implementation of an interface without implementing it for each implementation?

[image]

In the image above `IBase` and `Ichild` are classes having only pure virtual methods and `Base` implements the methods of `IBase` and `Child` implements the methods of `IChild`.
Is it now somehow possible for `Child` to inherit the implementations of the methods of `IBase` via `Base`, so that `Child` does not have to implement these methods itself?

I tried to implement it like this:

```
struct IBase {
    virtual void do_something_Base() = 0;
};

struct IChild : public virtual IBase {
    virtual void do_something_Child() = 0;
};


struct Base : public virtual IBase {
    virtual void do_something_Base() { //implementation IBase method
        //do sth
    }
};

struct Child : public Base , public IChild {
    virtual void do_something_Child() { //implementation IChild method
        //do sth
    }
};

int main() {

    IBase* B = new Child;
    B->do_something_Base();

    delete B;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the copiler gives a warning:

> warning C4250: 'Child': inherits 'Base::Base::do_something_Base' via dominance

Futhermore the program crashes at the line `delete B`.
(If I use `IChild* B` instead of `IBase* B` the program does not crash. why is that?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance

Comment: yes i know virtual inheritance, but there the compiler gives an warning. The warning says that the methods of `IBase` are inherited by dominance.

Comment: If you are having code error then please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: For the crash: `warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'IBase' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behaviour [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]`

Comment: I do not see virtual destructors in your polymorphic classess. I believe, it should be made a compiler error!

Comment: Yes if i add a virtual destructor to `IBase`it does not crash any more. But the other compiler warning remained.

Comment: @SergeyA: virtual destructors are only necessary to allow deletion through a pointer to a base class. All works fine if you don't, so it is only a warning.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - look at the code. Whis is exactly what OP is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using a similar setup in a project, and it works for me. It should be enough to do the following:

1. Give `IBase` a virtual destructor. A virtual destructor is *necessary* for being able to delete through pointers to a base class.
2. To be on the safe side, derive `Child` from `IChild` virtually as well. Since the `I`-classes have no data, there's no point in using them as *non*-virtual bases.
3. Disable the warning, as it's basically telling that the compiler is doing exactly what you want it to do (that the implementation is inherited from the correct base class).

Comment: what does a virtual inheritance of `IChild` do?

Comment: @Philinator Just like any other virtual inheritance - ensures that there is only one subobject of that type in the most derived object, even if more than one class derives from it. As you currently have it, you'll have one `IChild` present in the `Base` subobject (the virtually derived one), *and* one `IChild` present directly in `Child` (the one derived normally).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

The *inherits via dominance* is just a warning that can be safely ignored here because the dominance gives you the correct override of the method.

But the crash on delete is because the pointer to an object through one class and a derived one need not have same representation (*). And you forgot to add a virtual destructor in `IBase` and `IChild` while it is highly recommended for inheritable classes, and necessary to allow deletion through a pointer to the inherited class as stated by @Angew.

If you have good reasons not to have a virtual destructor (even if I cannot imagine one), you have to cast it to a `Child *` before calling delete on it. Moreover, as `IBase` is virtual, you must use a `dynamic_cast`:

```
delete dynamic_cast<Child>(B);
```

---

An alternative is to keep the original pointer that was returned via new and delete it instead of using the conversion to `IBase*`:

```
Child* C = new Child;
IBase *B = C;

B->do_something_Base();

delete C;  // deleting original pointer is safe
```

---

(*) just to be sure, just add to your code:

```
std::cout << "IBase*:" << B << " Child*:" << dynamic_cast<Child>(B) << std::endl;
```

Comment: That does not work for me because I have put `Base` and `Child` in a dll and they are not visible to the outside

Comment: Yes, casting it would work, but it's extremely cumbersome. Adding a virtual dtor to `IBase` is the correct solution.

Comment: @Angew: Of course! I edited my post accordingly giving you credit, but I leave it here, because casting could be an option.